# Populate specific json value to html with django template

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates

I am new to json and not familiar with it.

In my Django view file, I want to pass only certain json values: **school, address, each student's name (Andy, Tom, Jack) and id (Andy.id, Tom.id, Jack.id)** to the html from Django view. How can I achieve the above case?

my json content is:

```
{
  "school": "xxx", 
  "address": "xxx", 
  "number": "xxx,
  "students": {
      "Andy": {
        "id": "xxx", 
        "add": "xxx"
      }, 
      "Tom": {
        "id": "xxx", 
        "add": "xxx"
      }, 
      "Jack": {
        "id": "xxx", 
        "add": "xxx"
      }, 
    },  
}
```

In my view.py, I have got these codes. jresult is the json string and I used json.dumps() to generated JSON, but it will populate all the json data to the html.
How can I achieve the above case? Any helps will be appreciated.

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['file'].read()
            jresult = execution(file)
            json_string = json.dumps(jresult, indent=4)

            return render(request,
                          'virus/home.html',
                          {'json_string': json_string})

    else:
        form = FileForm()
    return render(request, 'virus/upload.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

my home.html template:

```
<body>
    <pre>{{ json_string|safe }}</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: @SachinKukreja So far I use json.dumps and render all the json content to the html. That is not what I want. I only want certain json value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip using `json.dumps` and just pass the `dict` object and then in template access the keys to get the values.

**Example**:

```
<!-- template -->

School: {{ json_dict.school }}
Address: {{ json_dict.address }}
<!-- and so on -->
```

Comment: So my json_dict would be jresult in my code? Could you please explain a little bit detail. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes. I suppose the `jresult` variable is a `dict` object on which you are calling `json.dumps` to get a string literal. But, you dont need that as you want the `dict` object to access the values in the django template.

Comment: I cannot make it..    my code: return render(request, 'virus/home.html', jresult)  and in my html:    <p>{{ jresult.school }}</p>

Comment: Update to `return render(request, 'virus/home.html', {'jresult': jresult })`

Comment: If you keep this `return render(request, 'virus/home.html', jresult)`, you can directly access `school` in html like `School: {{ school }}`

Comment: Did it. Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177049/discussion-between-luke-and-sachin-kukreja).

Answer (score 1):

A JSON object is very nearly a Python dictionary. With that in mind if you want to filter for just some keys in a dictionary you can use a dictionary comprehension and write something like:

```
jresult = {k:v for k,v in jresult.items() if k in wanted_keys}
```

Before you call `json.dumps` on jresult. Where `wanted_keys = ['school', 'address', 'number', 'students']`. If you are filtering the `'students'` dictionary as well you can do something similar to the above for that specific key.